# Call Page Javascript Methods from WatiN?

Tags: watin

I am just experimenting WatiN unit testing tool for ASP.NET application.. And my pages are designed with huge & complex list of own custom controls .. And its very difficult for us to identify the elements within these control (for ex: to select the row in our custom grid based on some business rules is very tough)..

so avoid this, I have planned to write all my test stubs in separate JavaScript library.. and call them from WatiN..(ex: A method which done some business validation on the grid and will select the particular row, and i need to call this method from WatIn).. I have actually implemented this approach but am getting Access violation error while calling the JavaScript method from Eval or Runscript method in WatIn..

Am not sure whether this is possible in WatIn..?? can someone clarify me??

Answer (score 7):

You call the DomContainer.Eval method.

Answer (score 1):

The RunScript method within WatiN has little room for reply. If the script you want to run contains an error of any kind, WatiN will throw the AV exception (this should definitely be improved). It is possible to do what you want-- I did the same thing with Infragistics grid controls.

Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with WatiN and had to add a number of extra methods that accessed directly the IE Browser Object to make this happen.

See the[O2 API/WatiN](http://www.o2platform.com/index.php/O2_API/WatiN) page for more details and specially the video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YsVX5-nGHWI which shows the HTML/JavaScript injection in action.

You might also be interested in the JavaScript parser integration that I added to the [O2 Platform](http://o2platform.com) using the [Jint API][3] (see http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_pqY_6-P-xU for an example of what I did with it)

[3]: http://www.o2platform.com/index.php/O2 API/Jint